# "Die Deutschen machen am Liebsten alles in Vereinen"

Tags: spelling

… bin verwirrt...
In der Januar-Ausgabe von *Deutsch perfekt* gibt es einen Artikel mit folgender Überschrift:

**Die Deutschen machen am Liebsten alles in Vereinen**

*Am liebsten* ist doch kein Nomen, sondern ein Adjektiv im Superlativ, nicht wahr? Warum wird es hier groß geschrieben?

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Rechtschreibfehler... schlicht und einfach...Du hast recht: das müsste klein geschrieben werden.

Comment: Ich habe auf [meta](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1628/1696) zur Diskussion gestellt, diese Frage zu schließen. Rückmeldungen dazu sind willkommen.

Comment: überflüssig, siehe @guidot bzw. meta ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es wurde groß geschrieben weil der Autor hier einen Fehler gemacht hat. Mit anderen Worten: Es ist falsch.

Deine Analyse ist ebenfalls völlig zutreffend: Es handelt sich um ein Adjektiv im Superlativ.

Die Wortfolge *»am Liebsten«* (in dieser Schreibweise) könnte aber in einem anderen Kontext durchaus korrekt sein. Beispielsweise könnte eine Frau ihren Ehemann als ihren *Liebsten* bezeichnen, und der Meinung sein, dass ein bestimmtes Kleidungsstück genau dann am besten aussieht, wenn es von ihrem Mann getragen wird:

> Der Mantel sieht **am Liebsten** viel besser aus als an jedem anderen Mann.

Ich gebe zu, dass dieses Beispiel ein wenig konstruiert ist, aber der Satz ist grammatisch völlig korrekt und verlangt die Großschreibung des Wortes *»Liebsten«,* denn es handelt sich hier nicht um ein Adjektiv das im Superlativ steht, sondern um ein substantiviertes Adjektiv, das natürlich groß zu schreiben ist.

Comment: vielen lieben Dank, Hubert! Die Großschreibung in der Überschrift war wirklich verwirrend. Ich dachte schon, vllt gibt es etwas Neues in der Rechtschreibung =)